# How can i fix my code to solve this syntax error in my config.py?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I create `config.py` file and run my Python code and it shows syntax error.

```
#config.py
API_key = GTW89NF3
mac = mac=6c:rf:7f:2b:0e:g8

File "flaskapp.py", line 8, in <module>
from config import API_KEY
File "/home/ubuntu/flaskapp/config.py", line 4
mac = mac=6c:rf:7f:2b:0e:g8
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please provide more context of what you're trying to achieve, which language and frameworks you are using etc. This looks like you're trying to write some python code despite being unfamiliar with the python syntax. Stackoverflow's purpose is to provide assistance with specific programming related questions. If you want to learn to write basic python code you could start here [learnpython.org](https://www.learnpython.org/)

Answer (score 1):

a `config.py` file usually has to be syntactically valid Python.

In Python, values that are strings need quotes around them:

```
API_KEY = "GTW89NF3"
mac = "6c:rf:7f:2b:0e:g8"
```

Also, it looks like the Flask app that you are using uses a config item called `API_KEY`, not `API_key`; generally Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you write `mac =` 2 times ?

Try going with one of these depending on what you want to achieve:

```
mac = "6c:rf:7f:2b:0e:g8"
```

Or

```
mac = "mac=6c:rf:7f:2b:0e:g8"
```